# Route::getRoutes() returns only package routes

Tags: laravel, routes

I am trying to fetch all routes in Laravel package using `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getRoutes();`. But it gives only package routes, not the entire Laravel application routes.

Is there any way to fetch entire Laravel application routes inside the package.

Comment: `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getRoutes();` will give you the list of routes registered. Chances are application routes are not registered at the time you execute the code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Route::getRoutes returns all routes declared in routes/web.php and routes/api.php. What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load the application routes first in order to be able to list them. So in your package Service Provider, within the boot method, you can load the routes from the application like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadRoutesFrom(base_path('/routes/web.php')); // or /routes/api.php
}
```

Then you can use

```
Route::getRoutes();
```